# Synthesis of an additional DNA in Pachytene and Zygotene

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics

I've read, that in Pachytene and Zygotene additional DNA material is synthesized, about 0,3, 0,1% respectively. Why is it so?

Comment: Is it possible to cite where you read this?

Comment: that's from one book, in Russian, unfortunately. But i can look for english source.
UPD: Answer below gave us english sources, i guess.

Answer (score 2):

About 0.3% of total DNA complement is synthesized during those 2 stages as a measure of replication repair mechanism.

Reference:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3731943

http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v219/n5153/abs/219489a0.html

Comment: Could you expand on this a little? Why is that DNA complement synthesized, and how does it act as a repair mechanism (and a repair mechanism to what)?